# image with letters such as gmail contact info - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-gradle-plugin

I am looking for a solution like the emails contact image list in gmail's android app,searching i found this library https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable so i try to use it with Android Studio, but while build.gradle compile... am error has occurred:

Error:

> Error:(12, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'TestDrawable' may be using a version of Gradle that does
>   not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file The build file may be
>   missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Someone has the same error ? how know fix it ? or another way to show a circle with the first letter of a List view name,

[Example Url image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioQAK.png)

Thanks.

Comment: This library don't help me, i follow 
[this tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122088/colored-boxed-with-letters-a-la-gmail) and add other stuff to make a Circle shape.

Comment: Too late reply .Glad to see that you overcome this .Happy coding #Fabi

Comment: Yei, a little bit late, i'll make a full example and linked here. Really thanks you.