# Make images with name initials like Gmail in Swift programmatically for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to display a profile pic of every user corresponding to his name in a UITableView. Until the image is downloaded I need to show an image with his name's first alphabet like in the GMail app. How to do this programmatically in Swift for iOS?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Something like this but for Swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122088/colored-boxed-with-letters-a-la-gmail

Comment: Do you want 1 initial ... then just create your own images, A - Z

Comment: Yes I want just one initial. I thought of reducing the app size so no images.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: http://www.paintcodeapp.com

Comment: This is great but sucks when used with other languages like Japanese where initials make no sense at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using FredLoh's suggestion :

I made a UILabel(nameInitialLabel) in the storyboard. Adjusted it's dimensions and font.

```
func setDefaultImage(name: String) {
    nameInitialLabel.text = String(name[name.startIndex])
    nameInitialLabel.backgroundColor = pickColor(name[name.startIndex])
    nameInitialLabel.enabled = true
}

func pickColor(alphabet: Character) -> UIColor {
    let alphabetColors = [0x5A8770, 0xB2B7BB, 0x6FA9AB, 0xF5AF29, 0x0088B9, 0xF18636, 0xD93A37, 0xA6B12E, 0x5C9BBC, 0xF5888D, 0x9A89B5, 0x407887, 0x9A89B5, 0x5A8770, 0xD33F33, 0xA2B01F, 0xF0B126, 0x0087BF, 0xF18636, 0x0087BF, 0xB2B7BB, 0x72ACAE, 0x9C8AB4, 0x5A8770, 0xEEB424, 0x407887]
    let str = String(alphabet).unicodeScalars
    let unicode = Int(str[str.startIndex].value)
    if 65...90 ~= unicode {
        let hex = alphabetColors[unicode - 65]
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(Double((hex >> 16) & 0xFF)) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(Double((hex >> 8) & 0xFF)) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(Double((hex >> 0) & 0xFF)) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    return UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

I've extracted the alphabetColors mapping array from https://github.com/uttesh/ngletteravatar

Answer (score 20):

[image]

"NO NEED ANY FRAMEWORK"

"Its Work Wonderfully"

```
@IBOutlet weak var IBtxtFieldName:UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var IBtxtFieldSurname:UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var IBImgViewUserProfile:UIImageView!


@IBAction func IBbtnShowTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
    let lblNameInitialize = UILabel()
    lblNameInitialize.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    lblNameInitialize.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    lblNameInitialize.text = String(IBtxtFieldName.text!.characters.first!) + String(IBtxtFieldSurname.text!.characters.first!)
    lblNameInitialize.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    lblNameInitialize.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    lblNameInitialize.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lblNameInitialize.frame.size)
    lblNameInitialize.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    IBImgViewUserProfile.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

"SWIFT 3.0"

```
@IBAction func IBbtnShowTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
    let lblNameInitialize = UILabel()
    lblNameInitialize.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    lblNameInitialize.textColor = UIColor.white
    lblNameInitialize.text = String(IBtxtFieldName.text!.characters.first!) + String(IBtxtFieldSurname.text!.characters.first!)
    lblNameInitialize.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    lblNameInitialize.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    lblNameInitialize.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lblNameInitialize.frame.size)
    lblNameInitialize.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    IBImgViewUserProfile.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great for me

Comment: Great. It works..!! But, why it is blurry effect ?? Can't we make clean text ??

Comment: To prevent the blur, set the scale:
 let scale = UIScreen.main.scale        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(lblNameInitialize.bounds.size, false, scale)

Comment: the text is to small at the center, how do i increase the size?

Comment: I did that by reducing the CGSize values, like half the size, updating the cornerRadius as well. Nice answer

Comment: For me its not round..
Fixed it by adding `layer.masksToBounds = true`

Answer (score 13):

This is perfect for the UIImageView: https://github.com/bachonk/UIImageView-Letters. Basically, it creates a UIImage with, at the center, the initial letter of the first and last word of the input. The background color can be random or assigned.

Here's an example of what this category can do:
[image]

[EDIT]

You may also want to check this out: https://github.com/bofiaza/IPImage

Comment: Do you have something like this for web? jquery / etc

Answer (score 4):

Updated :

```
     func imageWith(name: String?) -> UIImage? {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        nameLabel.textColor = .white
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        var initials = ""
        if let initialsArray = name?.components(separatedBy: " ") {
            if let firstWord = initialsArray.first {
                if let firstLetter = firstWord.first {
                    initials += String(firstLetter).capitalized }
            }
            if initialsArray.count > 1, let lastWord = initialsArray.last {
                if let lastLetter = lastWord.first { initials += String(lastLetter).capitalized
                }
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        nameLabel.text = initials
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
        if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            nameLabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
            let nameImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return nameImage
        }
        return nil
    }
```

[Reference](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/swift/initialsimagefactory-bb3b2084b76942d19272b698076537c8)

Comment: Interestingly, identical code was posted here https://swift.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/10915/generate-uiimage-of-initials-from-string and https://www.programming-books.io/essential/swift/initialsimagefactory-bb3b2084b76942d19272b698076537c8. Please don't forget to add a proper attribution if you reference material written by others.

Answer (score 2):

Add the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language).
I suggest you also add [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)

Add this code to however you are generating cells:

```
let profileView = UIView()
cell.addSubview(profileView)
profileView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.left.equalTo(cell).offset(10)
    make.centerY.equalTo(cell)
    make.height.width.equalTo(30)
//Your color
profileView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
let firstLetter = UILabel()
profileView.addSubview(firstLetter)
firstLetter.text = yourString[0]
//Add constraint for it, I suggest using SnapKit in which case
firstLetter.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
     make.center.equalTo(profileView)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple little extension, can be customised as needed.

```
public extension UIImageView {

    func addInitials(first: String, second: String) {
        let initials = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height))
        initials.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.height / 2)
        initials.textAlignment = .center
        initials.text = first + " " + second
        initials.textColor = .black
        self.addSubview(initials)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/bofiaza/IPImage,  but you must to do some corrections in function `generateImage()`.

Change this code in source file:

```
public func generateImage() -> UIImage? {

    let view = setupView()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    print(image ?? "No image")
    return image
}
```

on this:

```
public func generateImage() -> UIImage? {

    let view = setupView()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    view.layer.render(in: currentContext)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    print(image ?? "No image")
    return image
}
```

It will be work correctly!

Answer (score 1):

I updated Manav's answer

```
    func imageWith(name: String?) -> UIImage? {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        nameLabel.textColor = .darkGray
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        guard let initialsArray = name?.components(separatedBy: " "),
              initialsArray.count > 1,
              let firstWord = initialsArray.first,
              let firstLetter = firstWord.first,
              let lastWord = initialsArray.last,
              let lastLetter = lastWord.first else { return nil }
        nameLabel.text = "\(firstLetter.uppercased())\(lastLetter.uppercased())"
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
        if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            nameLabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
            let nameImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return nameImage
        }
        return nil
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Swift library for this :
https://github.com/ayushn21/AvatarImageView

It's highly customisable and uses a protocol oriented approach to get it's data and configuration

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view (UIView or UIImageview) and add a UILabel inside (centered vertically and horizontally)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).