# Android lollipop contact color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How do select color of contact badge. What algorithm using?

[image]

Comment: My guess it that it's just randomly chosen.

Comment: @JonasCz But after application restart  colors  will be saved.

Comment: Yes, it saves the randomly generated colors when it first generates them (when the contact is added)

Comment: @JonasCz Do you know approach to get color?

Comment: Okay, from the answers I learnt that it is not random, but generated based on the hashcode of the contact name. For generating a random color, try the answer below, or search for "generate random color java".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not save. It uses the hashcode of the Contact name string to determine the color.

Example:

```
String name = "Harish";
int colors[] = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};

int chosenColor = colors[Math.abs(name.hashCode()) % colors.length];
```

I learnt from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122919/3894784)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a Color generator like this..

```
public class ColorGenerator {

    public static ColorGenerator DEFAULT;

    public static ColorGenerator MATERIAL;

    static {
        DEFAULT = create(Arrays.asList(
                //your list of default tints
        ));
        MATERIAL = create(Arrays.asList(
                //your list of material colors
        ));
    }

    private final List<Integer> mColors;
    private final Random mRandom;

    public static ColorGenerator create(List<Integer> colorList) {
        return new ColorGenerator(colorList);
    }

    private ColorGenerator(List<Integer> colorList) {
        mColors = colorList;
        mRandom = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public int getRandomColor() {
        return mColors.get(mRandom.nextInt(mColors.size()));
    }

    public int getColor(Object key) {
        return mColors.get(Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % mColors.size());
    }
}
```